# How to performance test an Electron application?

Tags: reactjs, performance, electron, performance-testing, loadrunner

What options do I have to performance test an Electron application in a similar way to how Load Runner does it?

I need to performance / load test an Electron application built using React. The application is deployed to Windows 7 (possibly to Windows 10 as well) and invokes ReST APIs. 
I'm aware of the Spectron option but it doesn't sound like it is automated out of the box. I'd prefer to use a framework that already provides recording, playback, response time metrics, and configuring multiple scripts.
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) means [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP) so you need a performance testing tool which supports recording HTTP traffic.
2. The majority of performance testing tools provide TCP or HTTP [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) for capturing the traffic and converting it into internal form of tests

Assuming above 2 points you need to:

- Choose a [performance testing tool](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/testing-tools-overview/performance/?menu-page=overview) which suits your needs
- Configure your Electron application to use the selected tool as a proxy, your application either has its own proxy settings or respects underlying operating system proxy setup.

This way your Electron application will communicate with the backend via performance testing tool proxy which will be capturing requests so you will be able to replay them with increased load later on. Check out [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter) for example instructions.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I understand that I can test the ReST calls directly, but I want to test directly against the Electron UI, not against the ReST calls. Would you have some insight into that?

Comment: GUI Virtual User, Citrix Virtual User, Remote Desktop Virtual User, Truclient/TruWeb virtual user.

Ask yourself, what is the financial risk of failure?  If your effort to measure the risk aligned with the actual risk in terms of budget and management support?